# Subgroups of Symplectic Groups.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, symplectic-linear-algebra

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_group#Relationship_between_the_symplectic_groups), for commutative ring $R$,we have that $Sp(2n,R) \subseteq Sp(2n+2,R)$,
where

$Sp(2n,R):= \left\{ M \in M_{2n \times 2n}(R) : M^{T}\Omega M = M \right\}$

and

$\Omega := \begin{bmatrix}0&I_{n}\\-I_{n}&0\end{bmatrix} \in M_{2n \times 2n}(R) $.

However, I don't think that the 'usual' embedding

$M \hookrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}M&0\\0&I_{2}\end{bmatrix}$

shows this inclusion. I tried this approach, but I think that the rows and columns split awkwardly.

I feel that there should be a 'canonical' way to show the inclusion, but I have not been able to find a reference.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you've seen a treatment where the basis vectors are labelled by positive and negative integers (from 1 to n and -1 to -n), then you just add in new basis vectors n+1 and -(n+1).  The block matrix looks a bit messier, but the idea is the same as your matrix. Put an identity matrix in for the rows and columns in {n+1,-(n+1)} and put M in the rows and columns of {1,...,n,-1,...,-n} and put 0s elsewhere

Comment: As Jack Schmidt suggests, your block-diagonal matrix should have three blocks, $I_1$, $M$ and $I_1$, not $M$ and $I_2$. The reason for this is, if you look at the matrix of your form, the inner square looks the same as the form for the smaller symp[lectic group, but if you chose the first $n-2$ entries it wouldn't be right.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven                                                                                                    Sure, that seems to be right. But that still begs the question is there a more **conceptual** proof of the inclusion, or is there no way to avoid a nasty computation?

Comment: @SunnySood Since the form is a block matrix, the calculation is incredibly easy, no?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven So if you take the 2x2 matrix with entries (2,1;1;1), then I don't think the above construction works? (for example, the blocks for the corresponding matrix don't satisfy the symplectic condition)

Comment: I finally found a reference. See [link](https://www.ime.usp.br/~piccione/Downloads/LecturesIME.pdf)

Comment: Basically, if M_{1} = (A1,B1;C1,D1) and M_{2} = (A2,B2;C2,D2) are in Sp(2n_1) and Sp(2n_2) respectively, take block sum of A1 and A2 in the upper left corner, ...., block sum of D1 and D2 in lower right corner to get a matrix in Sp(2(n_1+n_2)).